# If I have an array of dates, how do I parse the months from each of those dates?

Tags: java, datetime

Month is an int array, which is being used to parse each of the months from the Date array.

```
public int [] getMonth() throws ParseException{
        String [] date=getDate();
        DateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yy hh:mm");
        Date [] result= new Date [date.length];

        for (int i=0; i<date.length; i++){
            Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
            result[i]=df.parse(date[i]);
            cal.setTime(result[i]);
            month[i]=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        }
        return month;
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare `month` array ?

Comment: the Month array is declared at the beginning of the class

private int [] month

Comment: `month` is not declared anywhere in the code posted

Comment: So, what's your question? Any problem with he code you posted? Which problem?

Comment: Well, the code that hd1 posted returns result which is a Date not a int array. But my question is how do i go about parsing the months from the date array and storing it in to the int month array.

Comment: So, I repeat my question: you posted some code which does that. What's the problem with the code you posted? (and please don't say "it doesn't work". Explain us precisely what happens when you run the code).

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at date.getMonth(date.java:139)
 at Testing.main(Testing.java:15)

Comment: And which line is line 139?

Comment: Line 138: cal.setTime(result[i]);

Comment: So, the line throwing the exception is line 139: `month[i]=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);`. And the exception is NullPointerException. What could be null in this line? What do you deduce? Do you understand the difference between *declaring* an array, and *initializing* an array?

Comment: public class Date {
 private int [] month;

My only guess would be the month array. Up until the getMonth method, I don't do anything with the Month array.

Comment: Your guess is right. Before storing anything in an array, you must *initialize* the array: `month = new int[date.length];`. Otherwise, the variable is null. `month` should be a local variable of the method, not a field.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that originally. Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here's my answer, but I hope that the lengthy conversation we had in comments will have learnt you how to find the cause of an exception, by carefully reading the stack trace, the exception type and message.

When you declare a variable, it doesn't refer to anything:

```
private int[] month;
```

is equivalent to

```
private int[] month = null;
```

So, you don't have any array yet, and you can't store anything in it. To be able to use it, it must be initialized.

Moreover, since month is only used in the method, it shouldn't be declared as a field, but as a local variable:

```
public int [] getMonth() throws ParseException{
    String [] date=getDate();
    int[] month = new int[date.length]; // here's the missing line
    DateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yy hh:mm");
    Date [] result= new Date [date.length];

    for (int i=0; i<date.length; i++){
        Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
        result[i]=df.parse(date[i]);
        cal.setTime(result[i]);
        month[i]=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    }
    return month;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net):

```
public int [] getMonth(){
    String [] date=getDate();
    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM.dd.yy hh:mm");
    DateTime result[] = new DateTime[date.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (Date d : date) {
       result[i] = df.parse(d).month().getAsText();
       i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope that helps.